# Angular 5 - bind two fields to single instance variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

For starters I'm using Angular version 5.2.11

In my component I have a timestamp stored as a string instance variable.

I need to bind that string to a form for the end user to update.  Normally I would create a template-driven form to update a string; but in this case I need the date portion of the timestamp to be exposed in the form UI as a text input field and the time portion of the time stamp to be exposed in the form UI as an option-select field (with a discrete set of available time values to choose from).

I've been cracking on this one for days now. After a while I gave up on template-driven forms in favor of reactive forms since that game me direct access to the form group; but I couldn't find a way to the inputs to set (or get) the values.  Eventually I attempted a custom form component--thinking I could write my own binding logic; but that's not working out either because the interface documentation assumes that your form component will have only one html input field/element.

I'm pretty much out of ideas...  Does anyone out there know of any working examples of a timestamp (or any other value) that uses two input fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can define two getter/setter properties, one for each part of the timestamp variable:

```
private timestamp: string;

public get datePart(): string {
  // Extract the date part of this.timestamp
  return ...
}
public set datePart(value: string) {
  // Set the date part of this.timestamp
  ...
}

public get timePart(): string {
  // Extract the time part of this.timestamp
  return ... 
}
public set timePart(value: string) {
  // Set the time part of this.timestamp
  ...
}
```

In the template, you can then bind each property to an HTML element:

```
<input type="text" name="date" [(ngModel)]="datePart" />

<select name="time" [(ngModel)]="timePart" >
  ...
</select>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xtxvf3) for a demo. Please note that a simpler alternative would be to have two distinct variables, `date` and `time`, each one bound to an element, and to define a `timestamp` getter property to combine the two parts.